# How to install ipa update without destroying user data

Tags: ios, air, itunes, ipa

I'd like to know how install an ipa through iTunes that is just an update to an app I already have. I am developing an app with Flash CS5.5 and AIR for iOS.

I can get the app on the device ok - I just drop it into the Apps area (under Library) in iTunes, and then perform a Sync. But if I have an updated version of the ipa, and I drop it into iTunes, it doesn't perform the sync - I suppose it doesn't think there is a difference.

I realize that I *could* just delete the app from my device and then install the new ipa. But I have lots of user saved data from the app stored locally on the iPad and I don't want to wipe that out.

Answer (score 3):

This is an oldie, but I was looking for an answer to this so...

The trick for me was to change the version and build number before exporting the ipa. Then if You add the app through iTunes, it will update on next sync. No deleting is necessary.

Comment: You also need to change the name of the ipa file on disk. Opening the same file in iTunes doesn't trigger update. Also drag&drop doesn't work anymore (at least not on Windows). You need to use "Add to library" function (CTRL+O on Windows).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, going to answer my own question... the trick was to delete the app inside iTunes first. So in 'Apps' under Library I needed to delete my app. Then I dropped in the new ipa, and when I did a sync it simply updated my app and kept the user data.

Comment: In case anyone still needs this, the best way to do it now is directly through USB with either Flash CS6 (check the box in publish settings) or with the command line tool 'transporter chief'.

Answer (score 1):

To add/update apps through iTunes, just follow these steps:

1. Open iTunes and select the 'Apps' tab (Ctrl + 7)
2. If updating, delete app (from iTunes, not the device)
3. Open (Ctrl + O) or drag-and-drop IPA file into the 'Apps' tab
4. Connect the device and select it on iTunes
5. Select 'Apps' tab of device and locate the app
6. Click on 'Install/Update' button, and then on 'Apply' to start syncing

IMPORTANT: When updating, always **make sure that the version number of the generated IPA is greater than the installed version**, in order to trigger an update.

Note that iTunes has a global 'Apps' tab, and an 'Apps' tab for each connected device, which are easy to confuse if you're not a regular iTunes user.
The global 'Apps' tab (Ctrl + 7) is where you drop the IPA, and the device's 'Apps' tab is where you install/update to the device.

There is no need to remove the app from the device (only from iTunes), unless you want to erase user data.